# Get global IP address from java http server

Tags: java, httpserver

I m starting a local http server using this code:

```
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    server.createContext("/intro", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null);
    server.start();
```

now I want to hit the url `/intro` from some other server.The problem is I don't know the ip adress to hit.Doing `server.getAddress()` gives `0.0.0.0:8000`.I want to find the global ip address.

Comment: if it runs on your pc then hit http:://localhost:8000/intro

Answer (score 0):

You have to know what is your ip (cmd and ipconfig) and get IPv4 address. But remember that is only your local IP visible in your local network, so only users in the same network can see it. In global network you are identified by your internet provider IP.

Answer (score 0):

> InetSocketAddress(int port)

Creates a socket address where the IP address is the wildcard address and the port number a specified value.

> InetSocketAddress(InetAddress addr, int port)

Creates a socket address from an IP address and a port number.

> The wildcard is a special local IP address. It usually means "any" and can only be used for bind operations.The value of this IP address is 0.0.0.0.

so use another constructor of InetSocketAddress when you can put hostname

> new InetSocketAddress(String hostname, int port) calls InetAddress.getByName(hostname).

Now you shall get your local ip address when you query server.getAddress()